# How can I loop through an array with razor and javascript together ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am currently using ASP.NET MVC, I am using javascript to create a graph that represents data in my models.
The Javascript is expecting the data in this format:

```
series: [{
        name: 'Bench',
        data: [
            10, 20, 30
        ]
    }],
```

However, I am trying to use razor to loop through my array in the data field as so:

```
series: [{
        name: 'Bench',
        data: [

            @for (int j = 0; j < numArry.Length; j++)
            {
                numArry[j] + ",";
            }
        ]
    }],
```

My issue is that the comma that separates my integers is not accepted by razor syntax. I need to comma to be repeated after every array integer otherwise the graph will only contain the last integer in the array.

```
series: [{
        name: 'Bench',
        data: [


            @numArry[0]
            ,
            @numArry[1]
            ,
            @numArry[2]
            ,
            @numArry[3]

        ]
    }],
```

This is my current solution that does work however, I can enter every element of the array manually.

Comment: Mixing backend and frontend languages is not recommended, as you get cases like you have here. Create a route in your backend which outputs an intermediate format, like JSON. Then request the data from the frontend with the Fetch API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it following ways..

1. Create Model with same structure and serialize it to JSON
2. Move the for loop outside of the series and declare a variable before the series code as below to get comma separated value.

```
@ {
var str = String.Join(",", numArry); 
}
```

series: [{
name: 'Bench',
data: [ { @ {str  } ]
}],